# remove a sublist from list in tcl

Tags: tcl

I want to remove a sublist from a list in Tcl. I know how to do it for main list using `lreplace` but I don't know how to do it for a sublist.
For example:

```
set a { 1 2  { {3 4} { 4 } } }
```

Now I want to remove `{4}` from internal list `{ {3 4} {4} }`.
The final list should be:

```
a { 1 2  { {3 4} } }
```

Please suggest how to dot his.

Comment: what we are missing is the criteria you need to select the element to remove i.e. is it always the 2nd sub-sub list in the 3rd sublist or something else?

Comment: also not lreplace actually creates a new list, it doesn't do an in place replace

Comment: criteria is if there are less than two elements in the internal sublist of list { {3 4} {4} }, remove it. like in { 3 4}, we have elements but in {4} there is only one element so i need to remove {4}.

Answer (score 2):

Combine `lindex` to get the internal sublist, `lreplace` to delete an element of the extracted internal sublist and `lset` to put the modified sublist back in place.

But honestly I have a feeling something's wrong about your data model.

Answer (score 1):

```
proc retlist {a} {
    set nl ""
    foreach i $a {
        if {[llength $i] > 1} {
            set nl2 ""
            foreach i2 $i {
                if {[llength $i2] > 1} { lappend nl2 $i2 }
            }
            lappend nl $nl2
        } else {
            lappend nl $i
        }
    }
    return $nl
}
```

If you need variable depth you're lost with this code. You need recursion for that.

```
% set a {1 2 {{3 4} {5}}}
1 2 {{3 4} {5}}
% retlist $a
1 2 {{3 4}}
```

As the outer list is never displayed in tclsh.

Answer (score 1):

It requires a few tricks to do nicely:

```
proc lremove {theList args} {
    # Special case for no arguments
    if {[llength $args] == 0} {
        return {}
    }
    # General case
    set path [lrange $args 0 end-1]
    set idx [lindex $args end]
    lset theList $path [lreplace [lindex $theList $path] $idx $idx]
}

set a [lremove $a 2 1]
```

This works because both `lset` and `lindex` can take paths, and they do sensible things with an empty path too.

Comment: I guess his problem would be to know the path... and therefore he needed to loop his list anyways to see which element of his list/sublist is a single value (his criteria).